# open function in c can't find a file when the file name is written with its directory

Tags: c, file, directory

The open function works fine when I try to open a file in the current directory but if I mention the directory of the file with its name as a parameter in the open function, the file is not found error happens. Also, when i try to open a file in another directory with the open function, the terminal prints there is no such file or directory. I can't find what is the problem with writing the directory of the file.

Right now I'm working in 'child1' directory and I want to open 'openthis.c' file. This is the code I want to execute.

```
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
int main(){
int fd;
if((fd = open("/child1/openthis.c", O_RDONLY) < 0){
perror("open");
exit(1);}
return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work but if I write

```
open("openthis.c", O_RDONLY)
```

instead of

```
open("/child1/openthis.c", O_RDONLY)
```

the code works fine. Why do you think every time I write the directory of the file, the file is not found?

Comment: What does `ls -l /child1/openthis.c` say?

Comment: Are you sure your folder is in the root directory of your machine?

Comment: @Mat it says there are no such file or directory, but when I do it with 'ls -l openthis.c' it works.

Comment: Then you do not have a file called `/child1/openthis.c`. End of story.

Comment: @rpadovani 'child1' directory does not locate right under the root, but it is located under the root several branches down. Do I have to mention the whole directory from the root like '/home / ... /child1'?

Comment: @Mat Then, how can I access openthis.c when I am working in another directory? I believe I do have to show some how where the file is located.

Comment: Yes. You need to give the actual path to the file.

Comment: Please show your actual code. The code in your question does not compile due to unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: A path name starting with `/` is an absolute path name; it's interpreted relative to the root directory. For example: `/home/yourname/dirname/file.txt`. A path name *not* starting with a `/` is a relative path name; it's interpreted relative to your current directory. For example, `dirname/file.txt`, assuming you're currently in your home directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's because your working directory has no directory named** `child1`**.**

> `open("/child1/openthis.c", O_RDONLY)` should be
> `open("child1/openthis.c", O_RDONLY)`, and it works like this:
>
> If your working directory is `child1`, it will search for `child1` folder inside the working directory. If found, it will search for `openthis.c` inside `child1/child1`, then opens it.
>
> `open("child1/openthis.c", O_RDONLY)` searches for `"child1/child1/openthis.c"`
> `open("openthis.c", O_RDONLY)` searches for `"child1/openthis.c"`

Let's say `child1` is your working directory and `openthis.c` is the only file inside it, no other folders/files. `child1/child1/openthis.c` will never exist unless you create a new folder inside the working directory (which is `child1`) named `child1` and add `openthis.c` inside it.

You can never access a non-existent file.

`open("child1/openthis.c", O_RDONLY)` will work fine if your directory tree is like this:

```
child1
   L child1
       L openthis.c
```

`open("openthis.c", O_RDONLY)` works because `openthis.c` is located inside your working directory.

Your directory may be like this:

```
child1
   L openthis.c
```